# Does my Windows 7 need reinstalling?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, reinstall

Almost every piece of software is working oddly and freezes. Explorer.exe, Blender, Speedfan, games, everything. To freeze explorer.exe for example I need to open USB Drive, get back and refresh. Then in search bar I see green progress bar for over 10 minutes. In Blender, every menu makes Blender not responding for ~10 minutes. Killing these processing (suspending, restarting) does nothing even in Process Explorer. Also Windows won't turn PC off. It's logging off, saving files and goes to infite loop in "Shutting off...". No IO activity.

So I have to turn it off manually. Then, when I turn on PC I don't get message like "Windows didn't shut down successfully".

I am not a pirate and also I know how to use Internet to get no viruses but just in case I downloaded Malwarebytes Anti-Malware and it found nothing. My system it's quite old (2013-12-10) but I would like to keep it. Do I need to re-install it or is there any solution?

Comment: Your question is far too broad/general and it sounds like you could easily benefit from a good hour or more of general troubleshooting and support.  There is no good single answer here.

Comment: You might have bad sectors on your hard drive.  Run **chkdsk**  Right Click C:  Tools  **Check** under **Error checking**.  If there is a check box to do the whole drive do so. **Yes** you want to do it on the next restart.  When you have 2 or so free hours restart and let it run.  Watch it for awhile and see how many if any errors it finds.  If a large number of bad sectors are found replace the hard drive.

Comment: If it finished in under an hour, open an administrative command prompt.  type **chkdsk /R c:**.  Yes, do it on next reboot.  Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks cybernard. Just ran chkdsk. I will tell you results when it finishes.

Comment: Okay. It took a few hours. In stage 1 it had 0 bad file records, 2EA records processed and 79 reparse records. In stage 4 it replaced bad clusters in a lot of files but just with extension like .png, .jpg, .wav, .ogg. Windows still acts the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is to create a new admin user via control panel. Reboot and login as this user. If the computer behaves exactly the same replace the ram as sometimes bad ram can cause the issues above. Also check the fan/vents for clogging/dust as overheating can cause strange things to happen to your laptop/desktop. Also, if you feel brave, try reseating the processor - make sure that you purchase some heat paste to put between the heatsink and the processor. There are plenty of guides online if you have any queries with doing this.

If after you have done all the above and there is no change, try a reinstall. Replace the hard disk and install to that to save you having to create backups. If the reinstall shows an improvement then you can easily transfer your information back from the other disk.

Your question is rather vague, but hopefully this information can help. Cybernard's chkdsk is also good advice.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyVegas for your suggestion. I will try it now and also I will run memtest this night.

Answer (score 1):

`sfc /scannow` into CMD (command line) as admin. This tool will check your system files for any corruption and fix them. Post results from C:/Windows/Logs/CBS/cbs.log

This link will guide you: [Sfc/Scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)

Comment: Didn't know about scannow. It said that it found corrupted files but it couldn't repair some of them. Here's my [log file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39l96jiKAYsRDFBMFg4c3h4ODg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: iassdo.dll.mui is corrupt and cannot be repaired. You should consider clean install or repair via install media.

Comment: So I will repair it, but this file is a culprit? What does it do?

Comment: Are you using cracked version of WIndows 7? This file is modified by  some crack tools. You should reinstall Windows 7 and activate it by legal serial number. If you have legal WIndows 7 - you should reinstall it anyways

Comment: Yes, because when I replaced my motherboard I had to re-install Windows and genuine key was not working anymore. But why it happened now and not when I installed Windows?